# Strange decrease in Reputation Score

Tags: discussion, reputation

I am pretty sure my reputation score yesterday was **2095**. It was 2080 prior & +15 was added by acceptance of an answer. But when I logged in today it is showing as **2087**. I tried looking at https://magento.stackexchange.com/reputation but didn't found any decrease in score infact the whole calculation is showing that my score yesterday was 2072 and +15 was added making it to 2087(which is not correct).

This is not the first time I see my score getting decreased by strange reason, it had happened previously as well but I had not kept note of score so I did not posted a question.

Is there a way where I can get why my score was decreased ? I know it can happen when someone deletes the question for which I earned reputation by making edits/answer. But can I see it in log ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know it can happen when someone deletes the question for which I earned reputation by making edits/answer.

Yes, that's the most likely scenario. It's a difference of 8; that could be an answer with 1 upvote and 1 downvote, or 4 suggested edits. It usually happens [automatically](/help/roomba) on old posts with low scores.

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/1266975/suggested-edits-by-user?UserId=77673), which looks at a snapshot from the Magento.SE database from last Sunday, tells me you have approved suggested edits on the following questions, all posted about a year ago, which have now been deleted:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283337/magento-2-search-pages-not-showing-filter-selected-option
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283258/display-b2b-feature-company-structure-in-magento-admin-panel
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283210/email-not-being-translated-viewed-correctly-what-is-causing-the-issue-and-how-c
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/283178/magento-1-9-order-total-as-zero-in-sales-orders-reports

Is it fair to lose those points? That's a tough question, but at the very least it's an incentive not to spend too much time on low quality questions.

(I've saved [a copy of the query](http://web.archive.org/web/20200725074455/https://data.stackexchange.com/magento/query/1266975/suggested-edits-by-user?UserId=77673) in the Wayback Machine, because tomorrow those records will be deleted from SEDE; almost all information about deleted posts is removed from SEDE.)

Comment: Thanks for given such a detailed info. Just a quick question, So next time whenever I get such behavior I can debug through the query you provided ?

Comment: Yes, if you do it before Sunday morning. Look for questions which are just over a year old (or 30 days / 9 days, see https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).